# Use $this and its protected variable in anonymus functions in php (5.3 !)

Tags: php

You know its not working in Php 5.3 but in 5.4, so a little workaround:

```
$thisObj = $this;
$thisObj->parameters = 1; // works!
$result = $this->method(function() use ($returnThisIndex, $thisObj) {
    $thisObj->parameters = 1; // wont work! Its a protected variable!
});
```

so here I pass a function to a method. The problem is, "parameters" is a protected variable, so it is still not seen inside this method. Then how to workaround this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a setting function within your class

```
public function setParam($param) {
     $this->parameters = $param;
}
```

Then in your anonymous function

```
$thisObj->setParam(1);
```